# incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine lists to create a matrix:

```
#reading all spreadsheets
genes <- read_excel("RNA.xlsx", range = "A3:B56321")
huh <- as.double(read_excel("RNA.xlsx", range = "LX3:LX56321"))
snu <- read_excel("RNA.xlsx", range = "AGS3:AGS56321")

#creating a data frame
df <- matrix(nrow=nrow(huh),ncol=4)
for(i in 1:nrow(huh)){
    df[i,1] <- genes[i,1]
    df[i,2] <- genes[i,2]
    df[i,3] <- as.integer(huh[i,1])
    df[i,4] <- as.integer(snu[i,4])
}
```

The error I get:

> Error in df[i, 1] <- genes[i, 1] :  incorrect number of subscripts on
>   matrix

Any solutions?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `cbind(genes[,1:2],huh[,1],snu[,4])`

Comment: The error is because the df is wrongly specified. You should try `df <- matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(huh),ncol=4)`